# OpenCV2.2 black screen problem

Tags: opencv, webcam

I am using a Dell laptop(Inspiron 14R) and trying to use OpenCV for one of my graduation project. But the webcam is not working properly. It is always showing a black window. Can anyone please help me. I have tried a number of suggestions but no result. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Opencv 2.2 has errors. Use either the latest SVN build, or an earlier version.

Comment: Duplicate? [Why does OpenCV give me a black screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720379/why-does-opencv-give-me-a-black-screen)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this thread](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/ticket/735) helps you. But I recommend to use OpenCV 2.1 for now, especially if you are using MinGW (GCC) as your compiler.
Assuming you are using MinGW, this is the [installation process](http://tech.dir.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/74105) for OpenCV 2.1.